# Laravel 8 update pivot table if nothing was edited in the form

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-8

I have a pivot table with extra fields ('tugas_1'-'tugas_10') with enum type, the point of this update is to modify those fields.

the problem is if the user open the modal form and then submit it with no changes, the pages goes blank but if I change one or more of the fields, it works. this happens if I only use the updateExistingPivot method so I solve this by checking first if the old value is the same as the request form value, then it will run the sync method. but is there any other way to solve this? and my code looks like a mess, I appreciate it if you know how to make it simple

this is my edit method on the controller.

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id_angkatan, $id_semester, $id) {
    $peserta = Peserta::where('id', $id)->first();
    $tugas = $peserta->semestertugas()->where('semester_id', $id_semester)->first();
    
    if($tugas->pivot->tugas_1 == $request->tugas_1 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_2 == $request->tugas_2 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_3 == $request->tugas_3 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_4 == $request->tugas_4 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_5 == $request->tugas_5 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_6 == $request->tugas_6 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_7 == $request->tugas_7 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_8 == $request->tugas_8 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_9 == $request->tugas_9 &&
    $tugas->pivot->tugas_10 == $request->tugas_10){

        $query = $peserta->semestertugas()->sync($id_semester,
        [
        'tugas_1' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_1 = $request->tugas_1,
        'tugas_2' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_2 = $request->tugas_2,
        'tugas_3' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_3 = $request->tugas_3,
        'tugas_4' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_4 = $request->tugas_4,
        'tugas_5' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_5 = $request->tugas_5,
        'tugas_6' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_6 = $request->tugas_6,
        'tugas_7' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_7 = $request->tugas_7,
        'tugas_8' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_8 = $request->tugas_8,
        'tugas_9' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_9 = $request->tugas_9,
        'tugas_10' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_10 = $request->tugas_10
        ]);

        if ($query){
            return back()->with('pesan', 'Tugas peserta berhasil diedit');
        }

    }
    else{

    $query = $peserta->semestertugas()->updateExistingPivot($id_semester,
    [
    'tugas_1' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_1 = $request->tugas_1,
    'tugas_2' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_2 = $request->tugas_2,
    'tugas_3' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_3 = $request->tugas_3,
    'tugas_4' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_4 = $request->tugas_4,
    'tugas_5' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_5 = $request->tugas_5,
    'tugas_6' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_6 = $request->tugas_6,
    'tugas_7' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_7 = $request->tugas_7,
    'tugas_8' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_8 = $request->tugas_8,
    'tugas_9' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_9 = $request->tugas_9,
    'tugas_10' => $tugas->pivot->tugas_10 = $request->tugas_10
    ]);


    if ($query){
        return back()->with('pesan', 'Tugas peserta berhasil diedit');
    }

    }
}
```

this is the edit form view

[image]

this is the table view

[image]

this is the pivot table
[image]

I hope you can understand my explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to update if there is no changes. Maybe what you're after is the sync whithout detaching

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id_angkatan, $id_semester, $id)
{
    $peserta = Peserta::where('id', $id)->first();
    

    $query = $peserta->semestertugas()->syncWithoutDetaching([$id_semester => [
        'tugas_1' => $request->tugas_1,
        'tugas_2' => $request->tugas_2,
        'tugas_3' => $request->tugas_3,
        'tugas_4' => $request->tugas_4,
        'tugas_5' => $request->tugas_5,
        'tugas_6' => $request->tugas_6,
        'tugas_7' => $request->tugas_7,
        'tugas_8' => $request->tugas_8,
        'tugas_9' => $request->tugas_9,
        'tugas_10' => $request->tugas_10,
    ]]);

    if ($query) {
        return back()->with('pesan', 'Tugas peserta berhasil diedit');
    }
}
```

Comment: no, if the user open the modal form and then submit with no changes, the pages goes blank and i just tried what you suggest, it says Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::syncWithoutDetach()

Comment: In this case, check if there is any change with javascript and prevent submitting if there isn't.

Comment: Nothing to do with javascript in this case

Comment: @MikkelNurfalah my bad, it's `syncWithoutDetaching`. edited it

Comment: i just tried that, it works when no changes, but if there are changes in the form, the pivot table is not updating

Comment: @MikkelNurfalah changed the format, it should work now no matter.

Comment: wow, i didnt notice you also change the format, thank you so much, now it works and the code looks clean now